# Sign in with Apple ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, asauthorizationcontroller

I am trying to prepare my app for the iOS13 "Sign in with Apple" feature. I have implemented the `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` methods and set my `ASAuthorizationController`'s delegate. When I tap the sign in with Apple button, after I enter the password there is no response. The password is correct (I know this because the field shakes when incorrect), however nothing happens. The sign in dialog doesn't dismiss and the delegates aren't called.

```
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    @objc private func didTapAppleButton() {
        let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let vc = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        vc.presentationContextProvider = self
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.performRequests()
    }
```

Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Same problem. I've made a gist with a minimal ViewController that replicates the issue: https://gist.github.com/phlippieb/8a250129fd11cbe0f7902981d612a0e8

Comment: Oh, interesting. When I deployed this to a real device, the sign-in flow used my face ID instead of a password, which seemed to work as expected -- the flow returned control to my app and called my delegate's success handler.

Comment: @PhlippieBosman see my answer below.

Comment: There seems to be something else going on with iOS 14: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533

Answer (score 3):

Do you allocated the code into a separate class so that your ViewController does not look like a trash heap? And you applied good practice principles to SOLID software development? Apl says - In vain XD!

**`Only ViewController can be a delegate.`**

It looks like a bug, alas.

Comment: I feel like the delegate is relevant to the view controller so it would be good practice to put it in the file. Of course only the signature needs to be there, you can put the actual logic in your view model if you wish.

Comment: Please check my answer. ViewController as a delegate is not mandatory. reference must not be weak or deallocated

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here. Need to go to [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and navigate to *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles*. Then under *Identifiers* choose the relevant app id and then add the *Sign In with Apple* capability. Note that you will have to regenerate the provisioning profiles for the app ids you edit.

Answer (score 1):

While following SOLID principal,
AppleAuth class' reference must be alive when `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` is being called. 
i.e. make your single responsibility class' object with viewController scope, not only method level scope.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apple Developer Account > Add 'Sign In with Apple' Capability to your app id (also make sure you've enabled it in Xcode too):

[image]

Keep Coding........ :)